# Why multiple unicode conversions String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0)) ruin the symbol in Chrome console and how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unicode, fonts, character-encoding

I have found this today and can't make out why it fails:

Basically if you take some obscure symbol like

`""`
then `"".charCodeAt(0)` in chrome console - you will get the code `55357`, but when you revert the operation with `String.fromCharCode(55357)` it produces `"�"`

Even if I do it like this `String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0))` it produces `"�"` however `String.fromCharCode("".charCodeAt(0)).charCodeAt(0)` is still `55357`, so information isn't lost, and it implies that it is Chrome that can't find correct symbol to map to `55357`.

**Why Chrome cannot represent symbol correctly? Is it because it cannot map it to font correctly? How do I make double conversion to be shown as `""` again?**

Comment: Sorry, JavaScript wasn't designed to manipulate Unicode characters that don't fit in 2-byte UTF-16 so they had to add an ugly hack called *surrogate pairs*. See georg's answer for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log

```
"".length
```

you will get `2`, that is, the string actually contains 2 characters, not one. This is because JS only supports 16-bit unicode (BMP) and encodes "astral plane" symbols with "surrogate pairs". Your symbol is `\uD83D\uDC49` internally, and when you do `.charCodeAt(0)` you only get `\uD83D`, which is invalid unicode.

More on https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Answer (score 1):

Following script will get the 'correct' char code (`128073`)

```
(("".charCodeAt(0)-0xD800)*0x400) + ("".charCodeAt(1)-0xDC00) + 0x10000
```

one then can convert it to HTML char code like this:

```
"&#x"+(((("".charCodeAt(0)-0xD800)*0x400) + ("".charCodeAt(1)-0xDC00) + 0x10000)).toString(16)+";"
```

And string extension:

```
String.prototype.charCodeUTF32 = function(){   
    return ((((this.charCodeAt(0)-0xD800)*0x400) + (this.charCodeAt(1)-0xDC00) + 0x10000));
};
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript to convert a text containing emojis:

```
 private emoji2html(text: string): string {
    const regexAstralSymbols = /([\uD800-\uDBFF])([\uDC00-\uDFFF])/g;
    return text.replace(regexAstralSymbols, (m, first, second) => 
      `&#x${(first + second).charCodeUTF32().toString(16)};`);
  }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: This solves the actual problem, reserving more space for an emoji than for usual characters ;)